# Why does the TextField in the List stop updating?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I started studying SwiftUI and wanted to make a prototype of standard reminders, like in an iPhone. It seems nothing complicated, there is a List, in each cell a TextField.

But I ran into a problem: when we change the text in the TextField using onChange, then we accordingly tell the view model to update our objects.

And when the objects are updated, the entire List is redrawn and the editing of the current TextField is reset (you can neither remove more than one character, nor add). You have to click on the text again to continue editing.

Does anyone know how to treat this?

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Fruit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    
    func updateName(newName: String) -> Fruit {
        return Fruit(name: newName)
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fruits: [Fruit] = [Fruit(name: "apple"), Fruit(name: "banana"), Fruit(name: "orange")]
    
    func updateName(newName: String, fruit: Fruit) {
        if let index = fruits.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == fruit.id }) {
            fruits[index] = fruit.updateName(newName: newName)
        }
    }
}

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.fruits) { fruit in
                ListViewRow(fruit: fruit)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(viewModel)
    }
}

struct ListViewRow: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State var fruitTextField: String
    let fruit: Fruit
    
    init(fruit: Fruit) {
        self.fruit = fruit
        _fruitTextField = State(initialValue: fruit.name)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $fruitTextField)
            .onChange(of: fruitTextField) { newValue in
                viewModel.updateName(newName: newValue, fruit: fruit)
            }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
```

Comment: use Binding instead of State

Comment: @loremipsum I really didn’t quite understand what I should bind with each other, can you explain more, please?

Comment: A `@Binding` keeps a reference to and passes the updated value of the bound variable in the parent view. The ` @State` only keeps its own internal value. When you update the parent's `@StateObject`, you are causing an entirely new `ListViewRow` to be created. Since you never kept the data that was entered into the TextField, it is started fresh with the name of the fruit you passed into the view in the first instance.

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui)

Comment: State and StateObject are sources of truth. Binding is a two way connection. Watch demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC21

Comment: @Yrb Honestly, I haven't fully figured out how to fix the problem, but thanks a lot for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it even more with:

```
struct Fruit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fruits: [Fruit] = [Fruit(name: "apple"), Fruit(name: "banana"), Fruit(name: "orange")]
}

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($viewModel.fruits) { $fruit in
                ListViewRow(fruit: $fruit)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListViewRow: View {
    @Binding var fruit: Fruit
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $fruit.name)
    }
}
```

That being said, you really need to view the Apple Swift Tutorials that were linked in the comments.

Edit: Full Project Code for Lorem Ipsum:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  FruitApp
//
//  Created by Developer on 11/27/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Fruit: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var fruits: [Fruit] = [Fruit(name: "apple"), Fruit(name: "banana"), Fruit(name: "orange")]
}

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($viewModel.fruits) { $fruit in
                ListViewRow(fruit: $fruit)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListViewRow: View {
    @Binding var fruit: Fruit
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $fruit.name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ListView()
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now it works as it should. Thanks for mentioning Apple Swift Tutorials, I'll dive deeper into this.

Comment: @Yrb Lol, so you just copied my answer and gave my advise and took at as your own? By your edited code even the `var` catch that you missed when you only copied part of my answer.

Comment: @loremipsum, no I didn't. You actually put your answer in a few minutes before mine was ready, but if you look more closely at the `ForEach`, you will see why I still posted it. I used a property wrapped array which will output a property wrapped element. You can then use that directly in the binding. That would be the simplification part. My comment of the simplification was because you posted first. I posted because I felt my answer was slightly better, but they were essentially the same.

Comment: @Yrb It is the exact same answer for the loop and yours didn't work initially because you didn't change the `var` in the `struct`. But that is ok I deleted mine I can undelete and you can see that there are no edits. No big deal I just pointing it out.

Comment: Actually, in my code in Xcode, I DID change the let to a var in the struct. I was just trying to put up the minimum necessary code. I then realized that I had to post that as well. I will update my answer with every bit of code. This really isn't a disagreement I want to be in as I respect your opinion.